Cannot find module '@/components/ui/toaster' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) in
I’m encountering an issue in my Next.js project where I get the following error message during the build process:

Cannot find module '@/components/ui/toaster' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I’m trying to import the toaster component in my layout.tsx file:
import Toaster from '@/components/ui/toaster';
The toaster.tsx file is located in the following directory structure:
/components/ui/toaster.tsx
I’ve configured the alias for @ in my tsconfig.json as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}



I’ve tried rebuilding the project by deleting the .next folder and running npm run build, but the error persists.
The toaster.tsx file exists at the specified path, and I’m using TypeScript in my project.

I’ve verified the path and the file name is correct (case-sensitive issues checked).
I’ve ensured that my alias configuration in tsconfig.json is correct.
I’ve rebuilt the project by deleting .next and running npm run build.
I’ve checked for any Webpack or next.config.js misconfigurations but didn’t find any issues.
I’ve checked for any missing or incorrect imports in my project.

What could be causing the error “Cannot find module
 '@/components/ui/toaster'” 

even though the file exists and the alias is correctly configured?
Is there something I’m missing with respect to how the paths or aliases work in Next.js and TypeScript?
I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you!
